# Best way to create separate heating zone for basement

Tags: heating-systems

I have 2 heating zone in the house: one for the upper floor and one for main and basement. Both zones split from the main duct into their own ducts and use a damper to close/open. 
Now I want to separate the basement in its own heating zone and wondering what is the best way to go about it. 
The heating ducts are separated for each of the main and basement heating vents, so my first thought was to buy dampers for all the upper vents/ducts and configure the basement zone to close those when blowing air into basement, but keep open the rest of the time.
Would this be something that could work or are there better ways to go about this?
[image]

Comment: This is prolly done already, but what is it that you are/were hoping to achieve here? Why does the basement need its own zone?

Comment: How would your heating system work if it was designed for 3 zones from the start? What's stopping you from modifying it into this configuration? Presumably the controller has a manual that will explain how you're supposed to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to possibly set a computer or manually controlled by pass. So when the upper floor vents are closed the volume of circulation is not reduced drastically.

Many of the modern heat pumps or furnaces have sensors reporting abnormal pressure or other conditions and put the system on hold, blinking an error code.

You need to read your equipment manual and be careful not to jeopardize your manufacturers warranty.

Comment: I added the image of that controller. It has the third zone avalable, so i was thinking that can be configured to certain blow pressure...

Answer (score 0):

What you are proposing is akin to "Variable Air Volume" control.  This is sometimes used in commercial applications where the air handlers are always running.  My experience is that it is a troublesome method due to the many failure points.

Certainly you could add dampers attached to controllers that would change air flow between the two zones.  You would need to create your own control strategy.